# Change CSS styles based on a numeric range

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, range

I have a temperature table and I would like to change the background-color of each `<td>` based on it's content. For example:

```
<tr class="temp-box">
    <td scope="row" class="temp-title">Máx(ºC)</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>
```

I would like a javascript/jquery function to check every `<td>` content and if, for example it is a numeric value from 10 to 15, changes the `background-color`to blue, if it's from 20 to 30, changes to red, and so on...

Any ideias?
Thanks!

Comment: I think if you have an array of colours ready, and then take the value module some appropriate number you'll have the proper index in the array.

Comment: Hey @joanaaarrr, welcome to S.O. What have you tried so far to change the colors? If you have some code, please edit your question to show that.

Comment: also, how is the table generated? maybe you could add different styles during generation ot the table?

Answer (score 2):

Add classes to `td`s and give color using CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td').each(function() {
      var text = parseInt($(this).text());
      if (10 < text &&  text <= 20) {
        $(this).addClass('red');
      } else if (20 < text && text <= 35) {
        $(this).addClass('blue');
      }
    })
})
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="temp-box">
    <td scope="row" class="temp-title">Máx(ºC)</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>22</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Function returns a color based on whatever logic you want
function findColor(value) {
  var colorMap = [
    { color: "#0000ff", min: 10, max: 15 },
    { color: "#0000ff", min: 20, max: 30 }
  ];
  var result = colorMap.filter(function(item) {
    return item.min <= value && item.max >= value;
  });
  if (result.length > 0) {
    return result[0].color;
  }
  return "transparent";
}

$(".temp-box td").each(function() {

  // read numeric value
  var value = parseInt(element.text(),10);
  element.css("background-color", findColor(value));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like the following:

```js
$('td').each(function(){
  var red   = Math.round($(this).text() / 100 * 255);
  var blue  = 255 - red;
  $(this).css('background', 'rgb(' + red + ', 0, ' + blue + ')');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>25</td>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>10</td>
  <td>34</td>
  <td>88</td>
  <td>70</td>
  <td>20</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

It's not capable of doing negative values, but it does show anything between 0 and 100 degrees in the correct color, and this can be adjusted.

Answer (score 2):

Using `addClass(function)` with a bit of logic based on cell values and a hashmap of classes

```
 var classes = {
    1: 'red',
    2: 'blue',
    3: 'green'
  }

  $('td').addClass(function() {
    var value = +$(this).text();
    if (!isNaN(value)) {
      return classes[Math.floor(value / 10)]
    }
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/yKeuONirycubLzIkQPT6?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

this creates a REAL green to red skala...

(of course you could tweak the values a bit, so that it fits more your needs..) =)

```js
$("tr.temp-box td:not(.temp-title)").each(function(){
  var r = parseInt((255 * $(this).text()) / 100);
  var g = parseInt((255 * (100 - $(this).text())) / 100);
  var b = 0;
  var bgColor="rgb("+r+","+g+","+b+")";
  console.log(bgColor);
 $(this).css("background-color",bgColor);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="temp-box">
    <td scope="row" class="temp-title">Máx(ºC)</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>60</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

More color options here for you... You can take your pick on how many options you are going to use and for which temperature span...

html:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <tr class="temp-box">
    <td scope="row" class="temp-title">Máx(ºC)</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>27</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>32</td>
    <td>31</td>
    <td>28</td>
    <td>24</td>
    <td>22</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#mytable td').each(function(){
    var currentValue = $(this).html();
    if(currentValue <= 20){$(this).css("background-color", "lightblue");}
    if(currentValue >= 21 && currentValue <= 24){
        $(this).css("background-color", "lightgreen");}
    if(currentValue >= 25 && currentValue <= 28){
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");}
    if(currentValue >= 29 && currentValue <= 31){
        $(this).css("background-color", "orange");}
    if(currentValue >= 32){
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");}
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/oquczbtk/